# proof that $[0,1]$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness, alternative-proof

I tried coming up with a proof of compactness of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and thought of the following method. please let me know if it is correct or how it could be made more correct.

For any open cover of $[0,1]$ there exists an $\mathbb{\epsilon}$ such that  $[0,\mathbb{\epsilon})$ is contained in one open set of the cover. Using the Least upper bound property of reals, there exists $l_1$ such that $[0,l_1)$ is contained in one open set $U_1$ and for any $l_1<m, [0,m) $ is not contained in one open set.

Now there exists some $l_2$ such that $[l_1,l_2)$ is contained in one open set $U_2$ and for any $l_2<m, [l_2,m) $ is not contained in one open set.

this way one forms an increasing sequence of real numbers ${(0,l_1,l_2..)}$ this sequence must converge to some $l$.

if $l\ne1$, pick an $\mathbb{\epsilon}$ ball around $l,$ such that $  (l-\mathbb{\epsilon}, l+\mathbb{\epsilon})$ is covered in one open set.
 since $l$ was the limit point of sequence ${(0,l_1,l_2..)}$,  $  (l-\mathbb{\epsilon}, l+\mathbb{\epsilon})$ contains all but finitely many $l_n$'s.

let $l_m$ be the first entry in the sequence ${(0,l_1,l_2..)}$ which belongs to $  (l-\mathbb{\epsilon}, l+\mathbb{\epsilon})$,

form a new increasing sequence $(0,l_1,l_2....l_m,l..)$ similar to the previous method. This way one gets a increasing sequence not bounded by any $l_n<1$.

So there exists an increasing sequence of $(0,l_1,l_2...)$ getting arbitarily close to $1$ and their corresponding open set sequence,$(U_1,U_2,...)$  .

since there exists one open set containing $  (1-\mathbb{\epsilon}, 1]$. so all but finitely many $l_n$'s are contained in that open set. So finitely many open sets $(U_1,U_2...U_n)$ along with the open set covering $(1-\mathbb{\epsilon}, 1]$ cover $[0,1]$

Comment: I don't see where your $l_1$ comes from.

Comment: Such an $I_1$ need not exist. Consider for example the trivial case where there is only one open set in the cover.

Comment: Ok, first I assumed that there exists an infinite open cover. $l_1$ is the maximum distance one can go from 0, which fits in one open set.

Comment: And open set containing $0$ contains some ball around $ 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof along your lines is possible, but you have to be more greedy when choosing the $U_k$. Your algorithm could stop short long before the right end is reached, and you would have to restart with no guarantee of success.

We are given a family ${\cal U}$ of open sets $U\subset{\mathbb R}$ that together cover the interval $[0,1]$. Put $x_0:=0$ and choose recursively points $x_k\in\>]0,1]$ as follows:

Assume that $x_0$,$x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_m$ have been choosen.

- If $x_m=1$, stop.
- If $x_m<1$, put
  $$x_{m+1}:=\sup\bigl\{x\leq 1\bigm| \exists\, U\in{\cal U}: \ [x_m,x]\subset U\bigr\}>x_m\ .$$ Since there is an open $U\in{\cal U}$ with $x_m\in U$ we can be sure that $x_{m+1}>x_m$.

I claim that this process will stop at a finite $m$. If not, consider the point $\xi:=\lim_{m\to\infty} x_m\leq1$. There is an open $U\in{\cal U}$ covering $\xi$
and therewith a point $x_m<\xi$. The inequalities $x_m<x_{m+1}<\xi$ then violate the choice of $x_{m+1}$.

We therefore may assume $x_m=1$ for some $m\geq1$. There is an $U_m\in{\cal U}$ covering $x_m=1$ and therewith an interval $J:=\>]1-\delta,1]$, $\>\delta>0$. By definition of $x_m$ we then can find an $U_{m-1}\in{\cal U}$ covering $[x_{m-1},x]$ for an $x\in J$. This $U_{m-1}$ will also cover an interval $J':=\>]x_{m-1}-\delta,x_{m-1}]$, $\>\delta>0$. By definition of $x_{m-1}$ we then can find an $U_{m-2}$, such that $\ldots$, etcetera. Proceeding in this way we obtain a finite sequence of open sets $U_k\in{\cal U}$ $\>(m\geq k\geq0)$ which together cover the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: So you are saying, the sequence of points chosen is such that, from any entry in the sequence, one moves as far as possible to the right which is contained in one open set. This sequence is increasing and will not be bounded by any point less than 1. Correct? I don't have to change the sequence this way. Correct?

Comment: More or less. An $x_k<1$ is not yet covered at the moment it is chosen, but all $x<x_k$ are covered by suitable $U$.

Comment: thank you. I knew there was something lacking in my method and it could be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> form a new increasing sequence $(0,l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_m,\ldots)$ similar to the previous method.

you're sweeping quite a deal under the carpet. What if it keeps going wrong and you habe to keep backtracking? In general arguments that simply state "continue this process to infinity" are likely to contain hidden subtleties, so I would require the details to be quite a bit more explicit before I would feel convinced by such a proof.

I *think* your approach can actually be made to work, but doing so rigorously would require you to speak about transfinite ordinals. Not something one would *want* to do for an elementary real-analysis exercise.

Instead it would to be simpler to cut through all of the piecewise step-by-step fog and jump directly to the end. Define

$$ B = \{ x\in[0,1] : [0,x] \text{ is covered by some finite subcover}\} $$
then set $b=\sup B$ and argue that

1. $b\in B$
2. $b$ cannot be less than $1$.

Comment: Cant I say there exists such increasing sequence going beyond any bound less than 1, I mean instead of constructing such sequence, can I say such a sequence exists?

Comment: @jnyan: That's essentially what I'm proposing at the end of the answer -- except you will find that then you don't need to speak about the _sequences_ at all, just the finite subcovers.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Your proposal solves it totally. Bear with me please. When you said,  " what if it goes wrong and you have to keep backtracking", can one get around this statement saying, given any such wrong sequence, there exists a new sequence, everytime and any given bound less than 1 can be crossed. I mean one does such argument in diagonal argument. I could use some help here.

Comment: @jnyan: You can indeed argue that given any sequence that reaches a too short limit, there is a longer sequence. What is not quite as easy is to get from there to "any given bound less than 1 can be crossed". The trouble is that if you insist on speaking of sequences, you would need to argue that "any given bound less than 1" is actually reached by a sequence. And you _can_ do that, but you then find that your argument for the _first_ part doesn't even depend on there being a _sequence_, so the work done in finding one is wasted (and likely to confuse a reader).

Comment: I am still having hard time to understand when diagonal argument technique works, which is about coming up with new sequence, how different is my argument. But thanks a lot sir. I will think more on the topic. I hope I didn't take much of your time